# Is it okay to cancel a CountDownTimer if it has been already canceled or finished?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that has 3 CountDownTimers attributes. When one CountDownTimer is running the other 2 are not running. I have implemented a method that cancel all the 3 CountDownTimer:

```
public void cancelTimers(){
    if (mCountDownTimer1 != null) {
        mCountDownTimer1.cancel();
    }
    if (mCountDownTimer2 != null) {
        mCountDownTimer2.cancel();
    }

    if (mCountDownTimer3 != null) {
        mCountDownTimer3.cancel();
    }
}
```

Now my question is, imagine that because I have cancelTimers() in various parts of my code (for example in onPause() and in showInterstitialAd()) (As onPause() will be executed immediately after showInterstitialAd()), cancelTimers() will be executed 2 times one immediately after the other. Is that a problem? Is it totally fine that cancelTimers() will be executed even if some timers have been just canceled or have just finished and called onFinish() method?

Comment: What Happened When You Tried It?

Comment: @user207421 it works okay apparently

Answer (score 1):

Digging down to the source code, you can find that [CountDownTimer#cancel()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java#93) eventually call [MessageQueue#removeMessage()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java#408):

```java
    void removeMessages(Handler h, int what, Object object) {
        if (h == null) {
            return;
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            Message p = mMessages;
            // Remove all messages at front.
            while (p != null && p.target == h && p.what == what
                   && (object == null || p.obj == object)) {
                Message n = p.next;
                mMessages = n;
                p.recycle();
                p = n;
            }
            // Remove all messages after front.
            while (p != null) {
                Message n = p.next;
                if (n != null) {
                    if (n.target == h && n.what == what
                        && (object == null || n.obj == object)) {
                        Message nn = n.next;
                        n.recycle();
                        p.next = nn;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                p = n;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which suggests nothing harmful would happen when `what` is not found from the messages list. It'd just loop through the list and do nothing.